# Find (presumably JS) code responsible of applying inline css style to element

Tags: javascript, css

I am working in a website I did not develop.

On page load and also possibly on window height change, a certain element receives inline style rules (max-height and height) by, presumably, some JS code, but I can't find which code exactly (several js files, including third parties').

How can I directly find the responsible code ? event listeners in devtools?

Thank you

Comment: Disable script tags until you find the one responsible...

Comment: The script loading scheme here is... convoluted. I was looking for a direct way to reverse-lookup the script responsible for such a change. Shouldn't there be a way to do so ? the browser is surely registering such change.

Comment: There are DOM breakpoints in your devtools

Comment: I found a better asked question, flagged my own question as duplicate. The question suggests using right click on element, then "break -> on attribute change" or similar, which breaks and highlights the relevant js code on style change... and seems available in Safari for example, where I was experiencing the problem.